# django error (no such column: projects_review.project_id)

Tags: python, django

I can't open my `Review` table, here's the models of code:

```py
This is the `Project` model:
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    demo_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    source_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    vote_total = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,
                          primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And this is the `Review` model:

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    VOTE_TYPE = (
        ('up', 'Up Vote'),
        ('down', 'Down Vote'),
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=VOTE_TYPE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

but I can't open my `Review` table on admin panel `(OperationalError at /admin/projects/review/)`

Here's the error details:
[image: error details]

I make migrations and do migrate:
[image: migrations]

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after you added the `project` field to your `Review` model?

Comment: yes i have do it sir

Comment: are you sure that there is no problem with your identation?, can you say whats was the output of yout terminal, when you make your makemigrations, migrate?, you can go to your migrations and see whats its going with your migrations, something on you migrations its wrong maybe

Comment: i've do itsir and ive upload the pics

Comment: Is `projects_review` an instance of your `Review` model? If so, are you trying to access the id field of the instance's 'project' foreign key field?

Comment: Can you please share your migration and settings file as well? And are you sure that the migration is not applied before?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like you need to create an initai migrations for your app - `python manage.py makemigrations projects`